# how to extract path from string in shell script

Tags: shell, awk, grep

i need to extract path from string

for e.g

```
title="set key invert ; set bmargin 0 ; set multiplot ; set size 1.0 , 0.33 ; set origin 0.0 , 0.67 ; set format x "" ; set xtics offset 15.75 "1970-01-01 00:00:00" , 31556736 ; plot "/usr/local/lucid/www/tmp/20171003101438149255.dat" using 1:5 notitle with linespoints ls 2'"
```

Then expected output should be

```
/usr/local/lucid/www/tmp/20171003101438149255.dat
```

using awk or grep

Comment: Are you asking for help to parse a file containing that text, or a variable named `title` set as you show (which then would be wrong since you're trying to contain `"` within a `"`-delimited string) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

**sed** approach:

```
title='set key invert ; set bmargin 0 ; set multiplot ; set size 1.0 , 0.33 ; set origin 0.0 , 0.67 ; set format x "" ; set xtics offset 15.75 "1970-01-01 00:00:00" , 31556736 ; plot "/usr/local/lucid/www/tmp/20171003101438149255.dat" using 1:5 notitle with linespoints ls 2'

sed 's/.* plot "\([^"]\+\).*/\1/' <<<$title
/usr/local/lucid/www/tmp/20171003101438149255.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` solution,

```
grep -oP '"\K/[^"]*(?=")' <<< $title
```

With `awk` solution,

```
awk '{match($0,/\/[^"]*/,a);print a[0]}' <<< $title
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter regex with `grep`:

```
grep -oP 'plot "\K[^"]+' <<< $title
/usr/local/lucid/www/tmp/20171003101438149255.dat
```